# Delphi: reintroduce and overload a virtual procedure

Tags: delphi, inheritance

i have the following virtual procedure:

```
procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(WorkIns: TWorkflowInstance; AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio); virtual;
```

In the inherited class i've defined the following procedures:

```
  procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(const AWorkflowInstance: TWorkflowInstance;
  const AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio; const AClientID: Integer;
  const AAttributeDataStructureID: Integer); reintroduce;

  procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(WorkIns: TWorkflowInstance;
  AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio); override; overload;
```

This doesnt work. How can i fix that? Or is this not possible?

Regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare all descending methods as overload:

```
  TMyClass = class
    procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(WorkIns: TWorkflowInstance;
      AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio); virtual;
  end;

  TMyClass2 = class(TMyClass)
    procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(const AWorkflowInstance: TWorkflowInstance;
      const AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio; const AClientID: Integer;
      const AAttributeDataStructureID: Integer); reintroduce; overload;
    procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(WorkIns: TWorkflowInstance;
      AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio); overload; override;
  end;
```

**APPENDED**

Upon the valued comment of @SilverWarior I add the following note.
The Embarcadero [Help System](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Methods) gives an example where the virtual method of parent's class is marked as `overload` as well. That can be done when it is necessary to add a new method to the descendant class with different parameters (`overload` it) but the same time you do not `override` the original method of the parent's class. In this case both methods will be accessible from the descendant class.

Comment: @DennisF. Welcome! Note that the help system gives an example and thus an advice to mark the method in parent class as `overload` as well. `procedure WorkflowInstanceInsert(WorkIns: TWorkflowInstance;      AWorkflowStudio: TCustomWorkflowStudio); overload; virtual;`

Comment: @asd-tm The reason why documentation also marks parent class method as overloaded is because the child class does not override the original parent class method but only provides overloaded method. Since in your example you are also overriding the parents method you don't need to also mark parent class method as being overloaded.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Yes, you are absolutely right.The method in the documentation sample is not overriden. I shall edit the answer.